# I want to use paypal payment for package sales, which paypal method woud be best?

Tags: php, paypal

I want package sales, when user click on purchase want to send user on paypal site, after success payment back to my site, I will update payment status if payed other wise will not update the payment status. 2nd question how will i know user payed?

Answer (score 2):

PayPal IPN allows the PayPal servers to interact with yours, telling them statuses about if they've paid, missed payment or it failed etc.

https://www.paypal.com/ipn

For example, if you're using the Website Payments Standard (https://www.paypal-business.co.uk/accept-online-payments-with-paypal/index.htm) you send them to the PayPal site by sending hidden information in a form, they do their thing on PayPal and then get sent back. PayPal will then notify the server using the IPN details that were either sent or are in the account, letting the server know if it was successful or if anything else happened. Then your application that picks up the IPN, does its security checks, and then does the appropriate action (e.g. allows the item to be sent or them to login etc).

However - if you're doing subscriptions, I **highly** recommend **not** using PayPal. They suck for subscriptions.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have site, where users will purchase package. I think ipn will be best for it, what you say dear?

Comment: Yes - I use IPN for sites that I've built that integrate with PayPal. As long as it's not a "subscription" package I recommend it, as PayPal doesn't allow modification of subscriptions to a great degree, which is rather annoying for users who want to change subscriptions etc

Comment: how can I add the price ? I need to add products on paypal with price or can pass the price and product info using paypayl paybutton?

Comment: You pass it via hidden forms. I suggest reading the PayPal documentation, it's quite good and will tell you how you can do it :-)

Answer (score 1):

visit the following link 
http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/paypal-php-integration

and follow the step by step guide.

If not work then ask question here.

Comment: how can I add the price ? I need to add products on paypal with price or can pass the price and product info using paypayl paybutton?